# Why can't *args be passed to super().__init__() from class that overrides int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, int

```python
class MyInt(int):
   def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
       print(repr(args), repr(kwargs))
       return super(MyInt, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       print(repr(args), repr(kwargs))
       return super(MyInt, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

MyInt(1)
```

This code outputs:

```
(1,) {}
(1,) {}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a45744cab1af> in <module>()
----> 1 MyInt(1)

<ipython-input-3-a38fc9aae2fe> in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      5     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      6         print(repr(args), repr(kwargs))
----> 7         return super(MyInt, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      8 

TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

It seems the base `__init__()` is expecting for args, because I can print them. So why can't I just pass them forward to the method of base class? (Btw, this worked fine in python 2.7)

Comment: `int` class instances are immutable, so their value is set by their `__new__()`, not their `__init__()` method, which doesn't accept parameters — something you can change or override.

Comment: If __init__() does not accept parameters then why I can print them? Also please see declaration of builtin class bool that overrides int. https://gist.github.com/grandquista/7b38e27bcf571b90d5254955abd7049e#file-builtins-py-L223

Comment: I meant to say "…something you **can't** change or override".

Comment: Ok, but why `int` passes parameters to my custom `__init__()`?

Comment: Because you defined it that way with the `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):`.

Comment: Do you mean there is some code that checks the __init__() signature before passing arguments?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. The issue is that `args` isn't being recognized by `int` and is simply being passed on up the chain to `object.__init__` (which raises an error instead of simply ignoring unexpected arguments). This is why the error message refers to `object.__init__`, not `int.__init__`.

Comment: Could you please show the place in the `int.__new__` implementation that decides to pass or not to pass the args to `__init__` depending the fact it is redefined or not?

Comment: I'm not sure it's in `int.__new__` nor where exactly it is — because it's due to how calls to methods _in general_ are resolved (mro) by the interpreter. Guess you could look for the source code that generates the `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters` exception. Could be in the implementation of `object.__init__()` itself (which would mean it's looking at the arguments _after_ it's been called).

Answer (score 1):

As `int` object is immutable, you can't use the `__init__` method. As it's explained in [this documentation](https://jfine-python-classes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subclass-int.html), you **only** have to use `__new__`.

Here it prioritises the `__init__` method when you create a new `MyInt`, and this is why you get the error. So just take off the `__init__` method and keep the `__new__` one.

Hope I got useful.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the words saying I can't use `__init__`. Can you please point out this please in the doc? Also why does this work for bool? https://gist.github.com/grandquista/7b38e27bcf571b90d5254955abd7049e#file-builtins-py-L223

Comment: @raacer "In many classes we use `__init__` to mutate the newly constructed object, typically by storing or otherwise using the arguments to `__init__`. But we can’t do this with a subclass of int (or any other immuatable) because they are immutable."

Comment: Have you took a look at `bool` implementation? And also have you noticed that `init` passes arguments to my `__init__()`?

Comment: The text provided above does not tell "you can't override __init__()". It just says "you can't mutate the object".